# App not showing in "Apps" in simulator

Tags: android, android-intent, android-browser

I have an app with the below intent in my manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.ui.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:host="myapp.com" android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

When I run the app from my IDE, it shows up on the simulator. However, it does not have an icon in the "Apps". So if I need to launch it again, I have to run the app again from my IDE.

If I change the Intent to just:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.ui.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN">
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER">
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

then it does get an icon in the "Apps" however, now I lose the other features i need - like `browsable` and `data`

**Question**

How can I keep the original intent and still have an icon for the app in "Apps" section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should split the different actions into their own filter.

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.ui.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:host="myapp.com" android:scheme="http" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

In your activity you can respond differently to the different actions.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
// To get the action of the intent use
String action = intent.getAction();
if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)) {
  //Do something
} else if(action.equals(Intent.ACTION_MAIN) {
  //Do something else...
}
```